# Specified cast is not valid in EmployeeUtilityClass

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, ado.net

i have a table empinf 
fields

```
Empid int
EmpName Nvarchar
Salary Numeric
```

i have a EmployeeUtility class which contains a Method Getdetails

```
public EmployeeDetails Getdetails(int employeeId)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SelectEmployee", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id",SqlDbType.Int,4));
        cmd.Parameters["@Id"].Value=employeeId;


            try
               {
        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (!reader.HasRows) return null;
        reader.Read();
        EmployeeDetails emp = new EmployeeDetails((int)reader["EmpId"], (string)reader["EmpName"], (int)reader["Salary"]);
        reader.Close();
        return emp;
    }
    catch (SqlException e)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Data error.");

    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }


    } 


EmployeeDetails emp=new EmployeeDetails((int)reader["EmpId"],(string)reader["EmpName"],(int)reader["Salary"]);
```

it shows an error in this line indicating `Specified cast is not valid.` please need assistance in it.

my employeeDetails class is as follows:

```
public class EmployeeDetails
{
    private int employeeID;
    public int EmployeeID
    {
        get { return employeeID; }
        set { employeeID = value; }
    }

    private string employeeName;
    public string EmployeeName
    {
        get { return employeeName; }
        set { employeeName = value; }
    }

    private int salary;
    public int Salary
    {
        get { return salary; }
        set { salary = value; }
    }

    public EmployeeDetails(int employeeId, string employeeName, int salary)
    {
        EmployeeID = employeeID;
        EmployeeName = employeeName;
        Salary = salary;
    }

    public EmployeeDetails()
    {
        // TODO: Complete member initialization
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
EmployeeDetails emp=new EmployeeDetails(Convert.ToInt32(reader["EmpId"]),Convert.ToString(reader["EmpName"]),Convert.ToInt32(reader["Salary"]));

//this assumes that you don't have NULL values in any of those columns, because if you do, it will fail.  It would be more safe to check for DBNull.Value before trying to Cast these values.
```

Comment: Thanks sir while converting to int32 it works now and in salary Decimal datatype. i added Convert.Todecimal(reader["Salary"])) and it works.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that this error is a runtime exception, and not a compiler error?

The problem is not with your `EmployeeDetails` class - but on one of these

```
(int)reader["EmpId"], (string)reader["EmpName"], (int)reader["Salary"]
```

One or more of the values being populated into the data reader cannot be converted into `int` or `string`, either because of a bad type or because it's null.

Since `EmpId` is likely to be an Identity column, and therefore not null, my money is on either the `EmpName` column being null or the `Salary` column actually containing a float, or being null.  In the second case, you could use an `int?`, unless it's just simply dodgy data, in which case make sure the column is not nullable.

You can use the `Convert` class for converting column values to .net types - because they will actually be Sql types.  That said, those types - `SqlInt32`, for example - does support casting directly to `int`, for example, but it will also throw an exception if the underlying value is null.  That said, so will `Convert`; so I suppose either will actually do.

Answer (score 2):

This is mostly a guess, but it could be this:

```
(int)reader["Salary"]
```

`Numeric` is a decimal data type, not an integer.  But you're trying to directly cast it to an integer.  If the `Salary` value in the database is a decimal, try changing the `Salary` value on the object to a `decimal` as well.

Note that you can easily debug this and narrow down the problem in the future by simply removing one field at a time and re-running the test.  When you remove a field and it works, re-add the field and it again doesn't work, you've found the culprit.

Note also that your exception handling is woefully poor form:

```
catch (SqlException e)
{
    throw new ApplicationException("Data error.");
}
```

Not only do you completely ignore the actual exception, but you replace it with another that's entirely devoid of context.  You should at least log the exception that occurs.

Comment: Sorry Sir i didn't pay attention to the Catch. i do that now. and thanks for assistance. it works now.